# Enumerate a property list item array using AppleScript

Tags: arrays, applescript, property-list

I am attempting to enumerate the RecentApplication > CustomListItems property-list item's array of a property-list file (.plist), but am having some difficulty with the syntax:

```
tell application "System Events"

  set the plist_path to "~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.recentitems.plist"
  set the plist_file to property list file plist_path

  set itemNodes to property list item "CustomListItems" of property list item "RecentApplications" of plist_file

  repeat with i from 1 to number of items in itemNodes

    set itemNode to item i of itemNodes

    display dialog text of property list item "Name" of property list item itemNode

  end repeat

end tell
```

I get an error that reads:

> "System Events got an error: Can’t
>   make every text of property list item
>   \"Name\" of property list item
>   (property list item
>   \"CustomListItems\" of property list
>   item \"RecentApplications\" of
>   contents of property list file
>   \"Macintosh
>   HD:Users:craibuc:Library:Preferences:com.apple.recentitems.plist\")
>   into type string." number -1700 from
>   every text of property list item
>   "Name" of property list item (property
>   list item "CustomListItems" of
>   property list item
>   "RecentApplications" of contents of
>   property list file "Macintosh
>   HD:Users:craibuc:Library:Preferences:com.apple.recentitems.plist")
>   to string

Moreover, if I change the code to:

```
  repeat with i from 1 to number of items in itemNodes

    display dialog i

  end repeat
```

I get a single dialog.  In other words, it doesn't seem to be examining the array itself.

What is the correct way to capture the PLI's array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
set itemNodes to property list items of property list item "CustomListItems" of property list item "RecentApplications" of plist_file
```

I needed to add 'property list items of'.